# Python - Efficiently applying function

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm prety new to python so my question might be basic but is there a way to change two variables at the same time when using a function.
my problem is i currently use a double for loop to do so and it creates a lot of useless values.
As we understand better by exemple, here is a rapidly crafted one:

```
results=[]
Q1=[1,2,3]
P1=[4,5,6]
def findcash(Q,P):
    r=Q/P
    results.append(r)
for i in Q1:
    for j in P1:
        findcash(i,j)
```

now you see my return vector will have values of 1/4 ;1/5; 1/6 ...
where in reality i would like Q1 to change when P1changes so results=[1/4 2/5 3/6]

Cheers

Comment: You cannot alter a global variable in a function scope unless you declare it `global` there.

Comment: Sounds like you want to `zip` the lists

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
results = [Q/P for Q, P in zip(Q1, P1)]
```

which is kind of equivalent to this: (not really, but the idea is the same (you know - like a zipper))

```
for i in range(min(len(Q), len(P))):
     Q = Q1[i]
     P = P1[i]
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results=[]
Q1=[1,2,3]
P1=[4,5,6]
def findcash(Q,P):
    r=Q/P
    results.append(r)
for i,j in zip(Q1, P1):
  findcash(i,j)
```